# Puxar a informação ultima informação que ira usar para fazer comparação

Tags: c#, mysql

Tenho uma duvida em SQL, o que quero é que o codigo puxe a ultima informação dessa coluna e compare com uma label so meu site, porem não sei se o Last Insert Id é melhor ou correto a se usar.

```
SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)
```

Comment: Qual o nome do seu campo primary key com auto incremento?

Comment: O nome do meu primary key é Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de utilizar o `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, é que ele só retorna o valor do `AUTO_INCREMENT` da sua tabela, no seu caso o 
`id`, mas caso ainda queira usa-lo, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM Rota;
```

Caso ainda queira o `Km_Atual`, você pode usar o `MAX()` com o `id`.

```
SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE id=MAX(id);
```

E para fazer a comparação:

```
if(Km_Atual == label1.Text) //Onde Km_Atual é a string em que você armazenou o que o select retornou e label1 é o nome da sua label.
```

Answer (score 1):

Para puxar a ultima linha você pode fazer isso:

```
SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1;
```